# IDE для написания SQL структуры таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, ide, поиск-программ

Подскажите хорошую IDE(если такова существует)

Необходима не только подсветка синтаксиса, но и подсветка возможных ошибок в коде.

Самое главное автоподставка: имен, типов, атрибутов и т.п. Юзаю phpDesigner но автоподставки в SQL там к сожалению нету.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Строго рекомендую [dbForge Studio for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/)

Написание SQL-кода может занимать много времени, но производительность помогут улучшить:

```
    Автоматическое дополнение кода — для быстрого создания выражений SQL.
    Форматирование SQL — для соблюдения принятого стиля написания кода.
    Шаблоны кода SQL — для быстрого сохранения и повторного использования фрагментов кода.
    Быстрая подсказка с информацией об объектах базы данных.
    Навигация по коду — быстрый переход по F12 к описанию переменной, редактору объекта и т.д.
```

Comment: Софт супер, именно то что нужно было, Freeware человеческое! Благодарю  плюсом и принятым ответом)

-------------------

Нашел на сайте именно мне подходящую http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html

Comment: ага, один из лучших решений, 4 -ый год пользуюсь)

Answer (score 4):

Еще можете глянуть:

- [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)
- [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog)

Answer (score 4):

Лучшее, как и многое от JB (имхо):
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: Для тех, кто привык к их IDE - наверное да :)

Answer (score 1):

Я предпочитаю юзать `Valentina Studio`
(http://valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview).  Шикарно работает на маке, винде и линуксе. Особенно на линуксе.
SQL редактор достойный. Не говоря про кучу других фич, которые есть в бесплатной версии.